# Subinterface in cisco router

Tags: routing, subnet

Quick question - I was learning about subinterfaces and using Cisco Packet Tracer I wanted to create simple network with two computers (every in different networks (192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.2.1/24 and different VLAN) and using one router connect them. So my problem is that when I was typing the network `R1(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0`
 wasn't working while `R1(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0`
 was working.
I'm just curious why there is there difference because both 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.10/24 will give 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254 host adresses.

Edit:
So to be more precise I was just pinging two computers and there was "Request timed out" message.
[image]

Comment: `wasn't working` isn't descriptive. You need to edit your question to explain it, and you need to include the exact message, if any, that you got.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: Please provide *configurations* of the switch and the router, without that it's only guessing.

Comment: OK, we are starting to get somewhere. It sounds like PC0 has its gateway as `192.168.1.1`. You should really include all the relevant information, including the router and switch configurations.

Comment: Well if PC0 has address 192.168.1.10 then you cannot configure that same address on the router a well.

Comment: That makes sense. Yes, PC0 had address 192.168.1.10/24 and gateway 192.168.1.1. So while setting up subinterface it's crucial to configure it with default gateway. Is that right?

Comment: The router is just another host on the network and just like the other hosts it needs a unique IP or it can't function correctly.  If you set it to 192.168.1.1 you should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides on what was already mentioned, just to answer your question, it looks like you are trying to setup an IP address in the router which already belongs to PC0. Take a look and notice as they are the same - and you might know that two devices can not have the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Default gateway missing on PC's.

Your hosts/endpoints need to have a default gateway in addition to an IP address.  Without the default gateway, the endpoint don't know how/where to send the packet for the other subnet.  The default gateway is going to be on the same subnet as the PC's NIC card.

Answer (score 0):

R1(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 wasn't working while R1(config-subif)#ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 was working.

This should work . When creating sub interfàce with IPaddress 192.168.1.10 . This ip address act as default gateway for this Vlans . But make sure you assign another ip address to Pc ,assign 192.168.1.12 to PC0 .